# cloudfront psudostreaming query string param

Tags: flash, streaming, amazon-cloudfront, flowplayer

I'm trying to setup flowplayer with pseudostreaming plugin  and amazon cloudfront for working together . It's all working fine, but when I'm trying to seek to another position the playback starts from the beginning.
I'm thinking that the problem comes from query string param **target**

```
lighttpd: {
    url: "flowplayer.pseudostreaming-3.2.13.swf",

    // use ${start} as a placeholder for the target keyframe
    queryString: '?target=${start}'
}
```

If you have any ideas or suggestions please help!

Comment: You didn't mention your CloudFront configuration. Are you forwarding query string at all? It is stripped by default: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/QueryStringParameters.html

Answer (score 0):

Because of bytes range request which is supported, I assumed that cloudfront support pseudo-streaming, but it looks they don't.Please see [flowplayer post](https://flowplayer.org/i/flowplayer/scripting_api:5075_cloudfront_mp4).